# Can the send_sig() function sleep in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, signals

Can I safely **use** the [**`send_sig()`**](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/kernel/signal.c#L1543) function in kernel-mode to send a signal to a process **from within atomic context**?
In other words, could this function block or sleep?

Comment: I would look at existing usage in the kernel to see. The contracts of kernel-internal are **extremely** under-documented, but if you find other places in the kernel are relying on it (or a similar interface you could use in place of it) being same from an atomic context, then you can conclude that you can do so too. Code for handling fatal error conditions, OOM handler, etc. would be good places to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the source code (v4.20):

1. `send_sig()` only calls [`send_sig_info()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/kernel/signal.c#L1526)...
2. ... which checks if the signal value is valid and then calls [`do_send_sig_info()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/kernel/signal.c#L1246)...
3. ... which calls [`lock_task_sighand()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L645)...
4. ... which has the function of locking the **spinlock** `tsk->sighand->siglock` (through [`spin_lock_irqsave()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L357)). This spinlock is only released at the end of `do_send_sig_info()`, which then returns immediately.

We know that kernel code must not sleep while holding a spinlock, as that would be a fatal error. Since the very first chain of calls done by `send_sig()` has the effect of locking a spinlock which is then held for the entirety of the operation, we can deduce that **the `send_sig()` function does not sleep**.